# Download all pdfs via links returned by Google search

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

Good day All,

Kindly advise on the process I can use to be able to download pdfs from links prefixed by [pdf] returned from by a Google search for example "astronomy pdf". The process should include a way to go thru all pages of results not just the first.

I've written a scraper before for text from a webpage using python (urllib, BeautifulSoup, webbrowser) with success but I don't mind doing this by another way [perl, bash, etc].

Kindly advise if further is needed on the above. Thanks for any assistance, advice given on this.

Comment: Your question has quite a broad scope. You should break down the problem and ask a set of more specific technical questions, if you want to get good answers on SO. If you have already know how to write a scraper, it should be easy for you to search the page text for the pdf links and download them. I might add that `requests` is generally considered a better library then `urllib`, so you could look into that.

Comment: Are there any "particular" domains you want to download? You might want to use Google Custom Search API. This way is way too inefficient.

Comment: You should maybe hire somebody to do it for you if you have no idea how to do it.